# Extract one specific value by resampling via rastercalc

Tags: raster-calculator, qgis-2.18

I am trying to extract specific areas from the following image: [image]

The grey areas are those of interest, they have a distinct RGB-value of 220-220-220. Thus, in my logic, the following code should leave me with the areas of interest in black and everything else white:

```
"image@1" != 220
```

Instead, I get an all black image - and I have no idea why. I tried to fiddle with brackets and conditions and stuff, but so far no difference.

/edit: Found the "solution". Yesterday, with .tiff-images, it worked. Today, with .tif-images, it does not. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather unspectacular problem: I simply chose the wrong output format. .tif does not work, .tiff does.

To be more precise: .tif is displayed incorrectly. Lower boundary is set to 0.99, upper one too, hence the image appeared black. Always an adventure.